# Does Naruto and everyone else know the truth about Itachi?

Tags: naruto

I know that Sasuke, Tobi, Madara, The 3rd Hokage and his 3 old advisers including Danzou know the truth about Itachi, as to why he murdered his own clan barring Sasuke.

Who else knows about this secret? Is it ever fully revealed publicly, and is Itachi ever stated as the true hero of Konoha?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naruto, Kakashi, and Yamato were told all at the same time by Tobi before the 5 Kage Summit.

Furthermore, Naruto had a very strong inference to go on when he fought the zombie-like Itachi and Pain in the 4th Great Shinobi War.

But the only person who knows of every single full detail is Sasuke as Itachi shared everything with Sasuke when they defeated Kabuto in the 4th Great Shinobi War arc.

Comment: to add to what you said. I think sasuke told the full story about Itachi when he met the dead hokages along with Orochimaru. This was during the time when sasuke was going to choose sides based on hashirama's explanation of shinobi.

Comment: @Bej Sasuke didn't cover "everything" he only asked about the parts that he believed Itachi may have lied to him about. And got more clarity on what it means to be a part of a village. At least that's what happened in the anime. in the manga I'm not sure.

Comment: That means, the answer to my question is that no one knows about Itachi other than these few people. That's soo unfair. ;-(. I was hoping that it'll get disclosed and everyone would appreciate Itachi for his sacrifice.

Comment: Unfair yes, but if it did get disclosed to everyone, then his character as the martyr of the leaf would be totally ruined. Compare it to how Lelouch went about his goal in Code Geass for instance. They are very similar in context.